# How to apply foreach loop in dynamic json in javascript?

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter-3, jtreetable

Before few days i get one static json to implement in my code from jsfiddle and did some changes to create dynamic json from it. [jsfiddle from which i got code](http://jsfiddle.net/adamjimenez/x9wd6k3x/)

Now My code is working.but i want some changes in it.Below is my current code and image that data i got from mysql with json.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('responsible/get_pay_slips'); ?>",
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            response = $.parseJSON(response);
            x = 0;
            $.each(response, function(i, value) {

                console.log(value.PAY_YEAR, value.PAY_MONTH);

                var data1 = [];
                data[x++] = {
                    text: value.PAY_YEAR,
                    data: {},
                    children: [{
                        text: value.PAY_MONTH,
                        data: {
                            price: 0.1,
                            quantity: 20
                        }
                    }, ],
                    'state': {
                        'opened': false
                    }
                };
            });

            console.log(data);



            // load jstree
            $("div#jstree").jstree({
                plugins: ["table", "dnd", "contextmenu", "sort"],
                core: {
                    data: data
                },
                // configure tree table
                table: {
                    columns: [{
                            width: 500,
                            header: "YEAR"
                        },
                        {
                            width: 300,
                            value: "ACTION",
                            header: "ACTION",
                            format: function(v) {
                                if (v) {
                                    return 'Print | Save'
                                }
                            }
                        },

                    ],
                    resizable: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    contextmenu: true,

                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Current flow of data:
[image: Current flow of data]
flow that i actully want:

[image: flow that i actully want]

So, How can we create `PAY_MONTH` of same `PAY_YEAR` in single tree.
i want only one parent `PAY_YEAR` and within it his all childerns `PAY_MONTH`.

I am using codeigniter.

My model:

```
public function json_get_slips()

    { 
      $empid ='34';     
      $where = "where EMPLOYEE_ID='".$empid."' ";     
      $query = $this->db->query("select PAY_MONTH,PAY_YEAR from india_salary_slip_details ".$where." group by pay_month order by pay_year"); 
      return $query->result_array();
    }
```

My controller:

```
public function get_pay_slips()
  {
    $data = array();
    $data=$this->pay_slips->json_get_slips();  
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

I dont know much about jquery and here i want to create dynamic data with it.I am hopeless.please help me with the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to fetch month your query will show only single month

```
                  SELECT CASE
                  WHEN salary_amt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE salary_amt 
                  END as salary_amt
                  FROM
                  (
                      SELECT 1 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 2 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 3 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 4 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 5 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 6 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 7 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 8 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 9 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 10 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 11 AS MONTH
                       UNION SELECT 12 AS MONTH
                  ) as meses
                LEFT JOIN salaryData e ON meses.MONTH = MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(SALARY_DATE,'%d-%b-%y')) GROUP BY meses.MONTH
```